# Comparing times in the 12-hour format

Tags: php, time

Can someone help and give a solution to compare two times which are in the following format when received: `12:20 AM`.

I have two time fields in my script which are meant to be stored in the database after validation, but after validation that the format is in correct order i want to do comparison between those two fields.

The comparison i want to do is to check if the second field not overlapping the first one.

**For Example:**

> The first variable is named `$timeStart`, and holding the time value of = "05:30 PM".
>
> The second is named `$timeEnd`, holding a value of = "4:00 PM".

Now, i want to do a comparison to see if the $timeEnd is before $timeStart **(also putting into consideration AM/PM when comparing)** if it is i dont want to echo an error, otherwise continue with the script.

I'm doing it for a Event Script, so timing has to be right :) $timeEnd has to be after $timeStart.

I sure do hope i explained it clear enough :(
Thanks for taking the time to read my complicated gibberish :)

Comment: you should add date too ... what start time is today 5pm and end time is also today 4pm??

Comment: lol, just got an idea - would i have to convert both times to MySQL Format to compare like this?

`$timeStart = date("H:i:s", strtotime($timeStart));`

`$timeEnd = date("H:i:s", strtotime($timeEnd));`

Would that work?

Comment: No, you need to convert them to **timestamps**. You can't meaningfully compare strings.

Comment: Na, you need the complete time, just this will do `strtotime($timeStart)` find the difference and and convert it to hrs or ... whatever

Comment: Thanks, the below function by Riky is working great, i upped for everyone, everyone was helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(function greaterDate($start_date,$end_date)
{

  $start = strtotime($start_date);
  $end = strtotime($end_date);
      if ($start-$end > 0)
       return 1;
     else
       return 0;
}
$time = greaterDate($start_date,$end_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
function timediff($start, $end)
{
        if($end >= $start)
        {
            return (round(($end-$start)/3600, 0))." Hrs ".((($end-$start)%3600)/60)." Min";
        }
        return false;
}
echo timediff(strtotime('yesterday 5 pm'), strtotime('today 4:30 am'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtotime($timeEnd) < strtotime($timeStart)) {
    // fail
}
```

Only makes sense though if you're not going to allow day crossovers, obviously.